# Jenkins Pipeline Exit if nothing in the folder

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline

I'm looking for a way to tell Jenkins in a stage that if there is no file in a particular folder he will cancel the job and mark it as unstable.

Could someone possibly help me? I think the whole thing can be solved with an if else query.

```
stage('Building') {
    if nothing in the folder {
        exit
        echo '[FAILURE] Failed to build'
        currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try the following :

```java
  def isDirEmpty() {
    def myDirectory = sh(script: "ls", returnStdout: true).trim()
    println(myDirectory)
    return null == myDirectory || "".equals(myDirectory)
  }
```

using the sh is the safest way of finding this thing out (from my experience)

Comment: Do you know if its possible with declerative pipline ?

Comment: Yep it does  ( we use something like this)

Answer (score 3):

This is a cross-platform method to check whether a directory is empty or not (you will need the [pipeline utility steps](https://plugins.jenkins.io/pipeline-utility-steps/) plugin).

Be aware that this function cannot be used when multiple executors try to access the same directory on the same node simultaneously, as the `dir` step will create a new entry for the other executors to avoid workspace sharing.

```groovy
def directoryEmpty(String directory) {
    dir(directory) {
        !findFiles().any()
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you know how we can make it in declerative pipeline ? with if & else ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the declarative pipeline syntax, but you could use this method inside a `script` block, or if you plan on using it multiple times you can put it in a [shared library](https://jenkins.io/blog/2017/02/15/declarative-notifications/)